# Bind a vue input that doesn't exist yet to a data property

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

We are using [Vex](https://github.hubspot.com/vex/docs/welcome/) in our application for all the dialog messages. I have an input in one of the dialogs that is used to filter a list of items.

In my Vue instance, I want to listen for the changes on a data property.

The problem is that Vue doesn't get the changes as I type them in the input box.  I am thinking this is due to the fact that the input is added to the DOM after the Vue initialization.

How would I approach this so my Vue instance can listen to the input changes? I've done my best to recreate the scenario in it's most simple form in the snippet below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    filter: ''
  },
  methods: {
    openModal: function() {
      vex.dialog.open({
        input: [
        '<h2>Filter</h2>',
        '<input v-model="filter" />',
        '<p>{{filter}}</p>'
        ].join('')
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vex-js/4.0.0/js/vex.combined.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vex-js/4.0.0/css/vex.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="openModal">Open Modal</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are providing plain html in strings to the `vex.dialog.open` method. Vue won't have any idea that you have done this and so none of the Vue syntax that you've included in those strings will be interpreted as it would in a Vue component definition.

What you should do is make a Vue component for that input, and then pass that input's element via a ref to the `vex.dialog.open` method. That way, Vue will have compiled the template before it's used in the dialog.

Here's a simple example:

```js
Vue.component('my-input', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Filter</h2>
      <input v-model="filter"/>
      <p>{{filter}}</p>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      filter: ''
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      modalOpened: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openModal() {
      vex.dialog.open({
        input: this.$refs.input.$el
      });
      this.modalOpened = true;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vex-js/4.0.0/js/vex.combined.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vex-js/4.0.0/css/vex.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <button @click="openModal">Open Modal</button>
  <my-input v-show="modalOpened" ref="input"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for: A clean and elegant solution.  Many thanks!